# Problema con una peticion AJAX con jQuery y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-get

tengo el siguiente '`$.ajax`':

```
$.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   'procedimientos/check.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type:  'post',
        beforeSend: function () {

            jQuery("#resultado").html("Déjame pensar un poco...");
        },
        success:  function (response) {
            //escondemos gif
            //mostramos salida del PHP
            jQuery("#resultado").html("response");

        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log(arguments);
            alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
    }
    });
```

Basicamente es una peticion **GET** que me trae los alimentos de **X persona**. Dentro de un directorio llamado **procedimientos** tengo un fichero.php llamado **check.php**:

```
   <?php 

    if (isset($_GET['usuario']) ) {

        include_once '../controladores/alimento_controller.php';

        // var_dump($_GET['usuario']);

        $result = alimento_getAllByUser_orderByTipoAlimento($_GET['usuario']);

        header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($result);

        exit();

    }

 ?>
```

Dicho fichero es el que llama mi ajax. **¿Cual es el problema?** Pues que no me esta trayendo nada. La funcion del fichero **check.php** (`alimento_getAllByUser_orderByTipoAlimento($nombreUsuario)`) funciona

El `$.ajax` me devuelve el siguiente **error**:

```
Arguments
​
0: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders()
, … }
​
1: "parsererror"
​
2: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
    jQuery 3
​
callee: function error()
​
length: 3
​
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function values()
​
<prototype>: {…
```

Comment: ¿Llega a procedimientos/check.php? si es así, luego ¿llega a la vuelta al ajax al success o al error?

Comment: Si cambio `echo json_encode($result);` por `echo json_encode("hola");` llega `"hola"`.

Comment: He puesto en el json del ajax la propiedad error . voy a reeditar la pregunta

Comment: primero tu peticion es `post` no `get` segundo valida que no tengas espacios luego del cierre o antes de la apertura de` php` ya que esto podria ocasionar el error y tercero no es requerido el `exit()`

Answer (score 1):

Porque usas GET si en el ajax indicas POST. Estas enviando un parametro vacio al query. Has un json enconde de la variable y veras como llega. El header tampoco hace falta.

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar esta mal el método de envio de tu ajax estas enviando un POST y en tu backend recoges la variables como si fuera un GET. En el ajax cuando es success estas imprimiendo un string en lugar de la respuesta obtenida del backend.

```
$.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'procedimientos/check.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type:  'GET', // cambia a GET
    beforeSend: function () {

        jQuery("#resultado").html("Déjame pensar un poco...");
    },
    success:  function (response) {
         console.log(response);
        //escondemos gif
        //mostramos salida del PHP
        jQuery("#resultado").text(response);

    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
}
});
```

El error que recibes en el success del ajax puede ser por que no estes regresando nada desde tu backend cambia un poco tu código a algo así.

```
<?php 
include_once '../controladores/alimento_controller.php';

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

try {
   if (isset($_GET['usuario']) ) {

        // var_dump($_GET['usuario']);

        $result = alimento_getAllByUser_orderByTipoAlimento($_GET['usuario']);


        echo json_encode($result);

    } else {
        $response = ["no se ha recibido nada"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $error = "Ha ocurrido algo.. ".$e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($error);
}
```

Me comentas sí te sirve.
Saludos